# How to refresh an icon that has been changed so the new one shows up?

Tags: unity, themes, icons, customization, panel

I want to customize two icons in the top right indicator of the unity-panel, the one for everpad and the one for deluge.

I found this solution:

[How do I merge two icon sets?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28592/how-do-i-merge-two-icon-sets/42571#42571)

...and love it, it's much better than how I usually try this icon things out. Having my own ~./icons/my-theme with an index.theme and some symlinks to some custom icons, as well as the "my-theme" icon theme selected (thanks to ubuntu-tweak), gives me what I want, and everything is working fine, but the problem is that...

...When I edit one of my custom icons, for example, if I change the color, the icon in unity-panel doesn't change. I have tried to use "gtk-update-cache" on "~/.icons/my-theme", but that must not be the way it has to be done to refresh the icons. And I know those are the icons I added...

So, can someone point me to the right direction as to how to refresh the icons that show up in this not-so-common circumstances?

Thanks in advance.

And my own big YEAH!! to pydave for that answer I just linked, I'd upvote it if I could.

Comment: Try this: [How do I restart an Unity session from the terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/q/38579/37006)

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I also tried restarting only the panel with "sudo killall unity-panel-service", but neither worked. Nor removing and remaking the symlink to the icon, or manually deleting the cache (ubuntu-mono-dark included, just in case), even trying in different orders.

Comment: But, forgetting the symlink commodity, hard-placing the icon in the ~/icons/my-theme/apps/22 or whatever the correct place, removing the cache, and restarting unity-panel-service (by killing it) DOES work... Using that for now. Hope to find something cleaner though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click [here](https://launchpad.net/~amith/+archive/ubuntutools/+build/3910667/+files/unity-reset_0.1-8_all.deb) to download a program called `unity-reset`.

Double click on the downloaded `.deb` file and install it.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Login

Run the command `unity-reset`.

For the full article click [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-reset-compiz-and-unity-in-ubuntu.html).